# Enviar una url a una base de datos

Tags: php, javascript, base-de-datos, insert

Imagen de la tabla imagenes: https://gyazo.com/df025c578ac72747788c8b5c20e6e725

Hola, estaba yo haciendo un juego de dibujar hecho con canvas y tengo un botón de "Subir" con el que me gustaría subir la url de la imagen a la bd.

Tengo una función con la que puedo crear una url del canvas:

```
function pujar() {
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");

canvas.toBlob(function(blob) {
    var novaImatge = document.createElement("img"),
    url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
    alert(url);

    novaImatge.onload = function() {
        URL.revokeObjectURL(url);
    };

    novaImatge.src = url;

    $('#pujar').remove();
});
```

Mi pregunta viene aqui: Hay alguna manera de llamar a un archivo php dentro de la función para poder insertar la url en la tabla? Ahora mismo mi archivo php está así:

insertar.php

```
include 'templates/database.inc.php';

//Per a afegir
include_once 'templates/magicquotes.inc.php';

try {
    $sql = 'INSERT INTO imatges SET url = :"contingut"';
    $s   = $pdo->prepare($sql);
    $s->execute();
}
catch (PDOException $e) {
    $error = 'No se ha pogut insertar la imatge: ' . $e->getMessage();
    include 'templates/error.html.php';
    exit();
}

header('Location: .');

exit();
```

Answer (score 0):

Lo primero que debes hacer es obtener cual es la raíz donde se están cargando las imágenes, algo asi:
 **./scripts/images/**
Esa seria la ruta donde se guardan las imágenes, luego la concatenas con el nombre de la imagen la cual puedes sacar en la función que tengas para adjuntarla

ya solo quedaría asignar esa ruta completa a una variable y guardar en la base de datos como un string.

En conclusión solo verifica que las imágenes estén subiendo al directorio, y luego de ahí se obtiene esa ruta con el nombre de la imagen que es la que se va guardar en el campo url de tu base de datos

Espero haberte ayudado con la inquietud.